# SSIS Warm Caches

Tags: ssis, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-comparison

Please see the following webpage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137786.aspx.  In the 'Caches of Indexes and Reference Tables' it states:

> "When you configure the Fuzzy Lookup transformation, you can specify
>   whether the transformation partially caches the index and reference
>   table in memory before the transformation does its work. If you set
>   the WarmCaches property to True, the index and reference table are
>   loaded into memory. When the input has many rows, setting the
>   WarmCaches property to True can improve the performance of the
>   transformation. When the number of input rows is small, setting the
>   WarmCaches property to False can make the reuse of a large index
>   faster. "

Where do you set Warm Caches? I have tried Googling this.  I have also looked in the Properties of the component.

Does 'Warm Caches' mean the component will use Fuzzy Groups that were created on a previous run of the SSIS package?

Answer (score 0):

the answer was below from the above BOL:

> At run time, the Fuzzy Lookup transformation creates temporary
>   objects, such as tables and indexes, in the SQL Server database that
>   the transformation connects to. The size of these temporary tables and
>   indexes is proportionate to the number of rows and tokens in the
>   reference table and the number of tokens that the Fuzzy Lookup
>   transformation creates; therefore, they could potentially consume a
>   significant amount of disk space.

This implies that if we select warm caches the temporary tables create are loading into the SSIS memory space similar to a fully cached lookup transform

The warm cache setting can be foun in the properties tab in bids:

[image]

"Pretty Sneaky SSIS"

Comment: Thanks, but the question was: Where is the warm cache setting in bids?

Comment: it is located in the properties tab. you need to scroll to the bottom, I'm editing the answer